# Add a button to add select-picker to add a new entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am completely new to the `web development`. Here I have a  `selectpicker` and there a data comes from a ajax call , SO, there I want to add  a button  to add a new entry in that , that time only . So, My code is like

```
<select id="selectJob" name="selectJob" class="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start" ng-model="formInfo.selectedJob" ng-options="job.uniqueID for job in companyJob track by job.uniqueID">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
</select>
```

So, I am using `angular js` , How can I add that  ? Any hint or help will be useful. And I tried using different things , can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a button push onto the `companyJob` array. How you have them input the data that you need is up to you, but all you have to do is alter the `companyJob` array and it will automatically change the options in the select

If you don't want to have it alter the `companyJob` array (maybe that is used elsewhere) make a temporary array for it and push onto that instead, and use that in your `ng-options`